# Some question about probability (i guess using Markov chains)

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I'm working on the following problem:
"A boy and his father are playing chess, and the game is set to be finished when one of them reaches $v$ victories. In each match, the boy has a $p$ probability of winning, and his father $q$. If $p+q<1$, calculate the probability of the boy's victory" I guess $p+q<1$ basically means that stalemates are possible. I was trying to use Markov chains but having to reach $v$ victories in order to win the game is causing me some trouble. Thank u so much if you read the whole thing :)

Comment: Backwards induction is probably best.  Label a state as $(i,j)$ if the son needs $i$ more victories and the father $j$.  Transitions are easy to sort out.  Note that the stalemate thing doesn't really matter, as those have no impact on the ultimate victor.  just replace the probabilities by $\frac p{p+q}, \frac q{p+q}$.

Comment: @lulu: Father and son are playing a straight first to seven wins type of match, so why would we need backwards induction ?

Comment: @trueblueanil  Where did $7$ come from?  But, sure.  You can do it for any $v$.  And, as you say, you can do it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify notation, let me call the initial probabilities $p' \; and \;q'$ for boy and father, $p'+q' <1$, and  ignore draws (which don't matter)

P(boy wins a game) $=p=\frac{p'}{p'+q'}$
P(father wins a game) $=q= \frac{q'}{p'+q'}$
but now $p+q=1$

*For concreteness, let $v = 7,$ say*

Since whoever wins $7$ games wins, it is like a tennis tournament where first to $7$ wins gets the prize, **and no recursion is needed**

You need a maximum of $13$ games to decide who wins.

The easiest way to compute this is to allow  $13$ games to played even if the match has already been decided, *but restricting the loser to a maximum of $6$ wins.*

Thus P(boy wins) $= \binom{13}0q^0p^{13} + \binom{13}1q^1p^{12} + \binom{13}2q^2p^{11}+ ... +\binom{13}6q^6p^7$

Restoring for the *v* wins needed, and making the formula compact,

$$P(boy \;wins)=\large{ \sum_{i=0}^{v-1}}\binom{2v-1}{i}q^ip^{2v-1-i}$$

If this seems counterintuitive, look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4219056/does-the-probability-of-team-a-winning-a-series-of-seven-games-depend-on-whether/4219083#4219083) where all doubts about the concept have been cleared in detail.

**NOTE:**
Had the question been that you need to win $v$ **more** games than your opponent, **then** it would be a Markov process.

Comment: Interesting formulation , aside form intuition I found an easy rigorous proof for such formulation 
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2188874) . BTW above it should be $2v-1$ not $2v+1$ which's the max no. of games to decide winner ?

Comment: @C.C: Thanks, typo corrected. The third of the "intuitive" arguments given in my linked  answer hints at how a mathematical proof could be written more formally.